# Different ways to solve x^2=x

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If I want to solve $x^2=x$ then obviously $x(x-1)=0$ so $x=0$ or $x=1$.

But, what if I try to solve it differently:

$$x^2=x$$
$$\frac{x^2}{x}=1$$
$$x=1$$

Then for some reason the solution $x=0$ vanishes. Apparently I am missing something. Question is: what am I missing and how to also get $x=0$ as a solution in the second method?

Comment: You can do it if you suppose $x\neq 0$, otherwise it's wrong.

Comment: Cancelling out a factor eliminates the possibility of you solving that factor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Division by $x$ is only valid if $x \neq 0$ here, that's why you cannot have $x=0$ as a solution with the second method.

Answer (score 2):

If we set $x=0$, we get $0^2=0$, which is true. OK, $x=0$ is a solution of our equation; let's move on supposing $x\ne0$. Now we can divide both sides by $x$, getting $x=1$. Fine, we have two solutions.